# Comparing arrays elements in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to learn how to think in a functional programming way, for this, I'm trying to learn Erlang and solving easy problems from codingbat. I came with the common problem of comparing elements inside a list. For example, compare a value of the i-th position element with the value of the i+1-th position of the list. So, I have been thinking and searching how to do this in a functional way in Erlang (or any functional language).

Please, be gentle with me, I'm very newb in this functional world, but I want to learn

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a list:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6]
```

Define a function f, which takes a list

- If it matches a list of one element or an empty list, return the empty list
- If it matches the first element and the second element then take the first element and construct a new list by calling the rest of the list recursivly
- Otherwise skip the first element of the list.

In Erlang code

```
f ([]) -> [];
f ([_]) -> [];
f ([X, X|Rest]) -> [X | f(Rest)];
f ([_|Rest]) -> f(Rest).
```

Apply function

```
f(L)
```

This should work... haven't compiled and run it but it should get you started. Also in case you need to do modifications to it to behave differently.

Welcome to Erlang ;)

Answer (score 1):

I try to be gentle ;-) So main thing in functional approach is thinking in terms: What is input? What should be output? There is nothing like comparing the i-th element with the i+1-th element alone. There have to be always purpose of it which will lead to data transformation. Even [Mazen Harake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46303/mazen-harake)'s example doing it. In this example there is function which returns only elements which are followed by same value i.e. filters given list. Typically there are very different ways how do similar thing which depends of purpose of it. List is basic functional structure and you can do amazing things with it as Lisp shows us but you have to remember it is not array.

Each time you need access i-th element repeatable it indicates you are using wrong data structure. You can build up different data structures form lists and tuples in Erlang which can serve your purposes better. So when you face problem to compare i-th with i+1-th element you should stop and think. What is purpose of it? Do you need perform some *stream* data transformation as [Mazen Harake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46303/mazen-harake) does or You need random access? If second you should use different data structure ([array](http://erlang.org/doc/man/array.html) for example). Even then you should think about your task characteristics. If you will be mostly read and almost never write then you can use `list_to_tuple(L)` and then read using `element/2`. When you need write occasionally you will start thinking about partition it to several tuples and as your write ratio will grow you will end up with `array` implementation.

So you can use `lists:nth/2` if you will do it only once or several times but on short list and you are not performance freak as I'm. You can improve it using `[X1,X2|_] = lists:nthtail(I-1, L)` (`L = lists:nthtail(0,L)` works as expected). If you are facing bigger lists and you want call it many times you have to rethink your approach.

P.S.: There are many other fascinating data structures except lists and trees. Zippers for example.